# Add Content-Transfer-Encoding to multipart/formdata

Tags: paw-app

I need to make a multipart/form-data request
Which should look like these:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
...Base64Content...
```

I know how I could transform a file into base64 but how can I add the Content-Type and the Content-Transfer-Encoding to a multipart/form-data field?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can work around this using the Base 64 dynamic value:

1. Set the body in Multipart mode, and add a new field `name`
2. In the value field, right click and pick Encoding > Base 64 > Encode
3. In that base 64 dynamic value's input field, right click and pick File > File Content
4. Pick the file you want to encode

Though, it's currently impossible to set custom headers in the attachment, so you won't be able to set the `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, unfortunately.

[image: Base 64 encoded file in Multipart]

Here's an example: https://paw.pt/aPPHzLRh (hit "Open in Paw")

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I already have added the file in the way you mention. Are you planning to add custom headers to attachments? That would be great or is it possible to write an extension for this? At the moment I only have the trial version but really like the program and think I will buy it. If it is possible to write an extension for this I would look into the documentation in more detail and write one. On a quick look I see no possibility to add more input values dynamically. To add as much header params as the user needs.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to achieve that through extensions, but we will definitely add custom headers in Multipart in a future release (no timeframe yet). Though, if you're interested in writing dynamic values (for other things), you can set custom inputs in them: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Create_Dynamic_Values_Extension

Comment: I need to be able to set Content-Type headers as well, still doesn’t seem to be a way. I’m not missing it, am I?